# How to dock border in stackpanel WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, border, stackpanel

How to dock `Border` in `StackPanel` in windows phone 8.1?

XAML:

```
<Grid>
      <StackPanel Height="89" Width="90">
          <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2"/>
      </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If `StackPanel` don't have height and width. Any another way by using `Grid`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for:

But why not put the `StackPanel` inside the `Border`

```
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="4">
    <StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Then it will draw a border around the `StackPanel`.

If the `Border` is inside the `StackPanel` you get a white line at the top.

Hope this helps